# UIButtons won't display in my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, cell

So I have UIButtons underneath a UILabel inside a CustomCell class in my UITableView. I got the label to show but can't seem to get the buttons to display. I've set constraints in all directions for all 3 UI elements in my custom cell.

I've also logged the frame of each button and they seem to be inside the frame of my cell.

Here is a screenshot of my story board and iOS simulator:
[image]

Here is the code I use to set up each cell

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [_questions count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

    cell.questionLabel.text = _questions[indexPath.row];
    cell.questionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.disagreeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.agreeButton.tag = indexPath.row + 60;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:[cell.disagreeButton viewWithTag:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[cell.agreeButton viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 60]];

    [cell.disagreeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.agreeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSLog(@"Button 1 Frame: %@\n", cell.disagreeButton);
    NSLog(@"Button 2 Frame: %@\n", cell.agreeButton);
    NSLog(@"Cell Frame: %@\n", cell);
    return cell;
}

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (senderButton.tag < 60) {
        NSLog(@"Disagree Selected\n");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Agree Selected\n");
    }
}
```

My CustomCell.h

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* questionLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton* disagreeButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton* agreeButton;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:[cell.disagreeButton viewWithTag:indexPath.row]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:[cell.agreeButton viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 60]];

[cell.disagreeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.agreeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Remove these lines and see.When you give custom class to cell then you don't have to subView again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom class then there is no need to add button as subview. But if you want to add button as subview using tag then use-

`[cell.contentView addSubview:[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row]];`

and

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 60]];
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the height of the displayed cell is to small to show the buttons, for this reason the button are cut off. Try to implement also this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{      
    return 300
}
```

Just try with 300 as height of your cells. If you can see the buttons than you can return the right height of your cells.